# Should i login to my ebanking account through frames in another website?

Tags: credit-card, iframe

During a credit card payment to site X , it asks me to login to my ebanking account through a frame in a site that handles that transaction in order to implement a more secure authentication (3d secure).
My question is : Should i trust such a process when i just see a frame that looks like a login page from my ebanking account when the url is different and it's a frame inside another webpage?

After searching , i think my question could become more focused: Is there a browser supporting a way to check the security certificate for the contents of an iframe ?

Comment: Single origin policy prevents website to hijack contents of an iframe. But iframes can be deceptive.